# Orthogonality of vectors in a Hilbert space

Tags: orthogonality

> Given vectors $f,g$ in a Hilbert space $H$, we say that $f$ is *orthogonal* to $g$, written $f \perp g$, if $\langle f,g \rangle = 0$. For sets $A$ and $B$ in $H$ we write $A \perp B$ if $\langle f,g \rangle = 0$ for all $f \in A$ and $g \in B$. Finally, $A^\perp$ is the set of all vectors $f \in H$ such that $f \perp g$ for all $g \in A$; for any set $A$ this is always a subspace of $H$. Morover, since $A^\perp = \bigcap_{a \in A} \{a\}^\perp$, $A^\perp$ is a closed subspace by continuity of the inner product.
>
> It should be clear that $A \cap A^\perp = \{0\}$. (Why?)

I know this is a trivial statement, but I am overthinking this. How can I prove that $A \cap A^\perp = \{0\}$?

I was thinking that if we fix a vector, say, $a \in A$, $b \in A^\perp$, then $\langle a,b \rangle = 0$.

Comment: si $\mapsto$ if $\:$ ? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Oops, learning to speak French got to me. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there was some nontrivial $v$ in the intersection. Then $v \in A$. So $v$ is perpendicular to every vector in $A^\perp$. In particular Then $v$ would be perpendicular to itself, as $v \in A^\perp$. So $$|v|^2=\langle v,v\rangle=0$$ So v must be 0.

Comment: So we can fix $v \in A$ and $v \in A^\perp$?

Comment: I made it more clear in my answer above. The idea is to assume that $v$ is in the intersection, and go from there.

Comment: Here is what I understand now so far: Fix $v \in A \cap A^\perp$. Then $v \in A$ and $v \in A^\perp$. Thus, $v \perp v$, which means $\langle v,v \rangle = 0$. If $v$ were nonzero, then $\langle v,v \rangle \not= 0$. Therefore, $v=0$.

Comment: Yup. That's the whole thing.